# How can I post something to a Wall using Facebook Developer Toolkit?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

Does anyone have experience using the Facebook Developer Toolkit?  I am trying to post something to a Facebook user's Wall, but can't figure out how to use the API?  Could someone could give me an example or point me to some documentation on the API's usage?

Comment: You might get a better response here http://forum.developers.facebook.com/

Comment: For anyone starting a new app you may want to check out the new Facebook C# SDK on Codeplex at http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com or at http://microsoft.com/facebook/

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1438976.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found documentation and samples to do what I was looking for here:  http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=28001

EDIT:
After initializing the Facebook session I called the Stream.Publish() method on the API.

```
FacebookService.API.stream.publish(...);
```

Comment: I have been messing around with the new 3.0 version. I am not able to connect. Can you post some of your connection code?

Answer (score 2):

I created a video tutorial showing how to do exactly this. Here is the link:

http://www.markhagan.me/Samples/Grant-Access-And-Post-As-Facebook-User-ASPNet

And here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using Facebook;

namespace FBO
{
    public partial class facebooksync : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckAuthorization();
        }

        private void CheckAuthorization()
        {
            string app_id = "374961455917802";
            string app_secret = "9153b340ee604f7917fd57c7ab08b3fa";
            string scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages";

            if (Request["code"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                    app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
                    app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                    string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                    {
                        //meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jake&...
                        tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                            token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                    }
                }

                string access_token = tokens["access_token"];

                var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);

                client.Post("/me/feed", new { message = "markhagan.me video tutorial" });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but maybe it still helps others: http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=75412