# ASP.NET MVC Facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I am trying to do a seemingly simple thing, but having trouble accomplishing it. I am trying to automate the posting on my Facebook wall. Basically I have a ASP.NET MVC website that I post updates on, and I want to automatically submit the post to my wall.

I see a lot of stuff on FB Connect and getting data, I just want to post.

Thanks for any help or guidance.

**UPDATE:** Just trying to resurrect and be a little more clear in my description as I am not getting anywhere.

I have a page that I want with a text box and a button. When I submit the form I want the message to post to **my** Facebook wall. I thought it was Facebook Connect, but I am getting no where as to how to automatically authenticate myself and post to my wall.

I would like to use C# rather than JavaScript.

```
private const string ApplicationKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
private const string SecretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
private Facebook.Rest.Api _facebookAPI;
private Facebook.Session.ConnectSession _connectSession;

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
{
    _connectSession = new Facebook.Session.ConnectSession(ApplicationKey, SecretKey);
    if (_connectSession.IsConnected())
    {
        _facebookAPI = new Facebook.Rest.Api(_connectSession);
        string response = _facebookAPI.Stream.Publish("This is a generated test");
    }
        return View();
    }
}
```

The IsConnected() is returning false.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @durilai: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166229/how-can-i-post-something-to-a-wall-using-facebook-developer-toolkit  did you search for an answer first?

Comment: I saw that post along with a bunch of others that do not match what I am attempting. On that specific post, it deals with an older version of the Facebook SDK. I am stumped so I asked for help. If you look I asked for help there first, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code was right, the problem was that I had not added my application to my profile. Dumb miss, but my thought is that the whole thing is poorly documented. I have another issue with offline access, but that is for a different post.

```
string apiKey = "XXXXXXXXX";
string apiSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
Facebook.Session.ConnectSession._connectSession = new Facebook.Session.ConnectSession(apiKey, apiSecret);
if (_connectSession.IsConnected)
{
    Facebook.Rest.Api api = new Facebook.Rest.Api(_connectSession);
    string response = api.Stream.Publish("Test", null, null, null, api.Users.Session.UserId);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I had not added my application to my profile"?
I think I have the same exact problem!

Comment: I created a Facebook application and then added it to my profile. After that it worked fine. I never got it working as seamless as I wanted, and I still agree with my quote on documentation sucking!

Comment: Im sorry, but I cant solve my Problem! I now even added my application to my Facebook Profile! If there is no new solution coming up, I have to start another Thread here with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you tested your Website on your localhost. The Facebook Cookie is not written out, when you test your Website on localhost. See this link http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=247332

This might solve your problem:

1. Add "127.0.0.1    localhost.local" to your file
2. Update your FB application Connect settings to use "http://localhost.local/" URL and "localhost.local" domain.
3. Create an IIS Web site on port 80 with the name "localhost.local". I had to stop my default web site, which is also on port 80
4. Update my Visual Studio 2010 web application to use IIS with the "http://localhost.local/" url.

To see cookies, make sure to install FireCookies, along with FireBug.