# Create Facebook app to post on wall using C#

Tags: c#, facebook

Is there a way of creating a Facebook app that will allow you to post on someones wall using C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I post something to a Wall using Facebook Developer Toolkit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166229/how-can-i-post-something-to-a-wall-using-facebook-developer-toolkit)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. 
(Don't downvote - I answered the question perfectly)

Comment: Joking apart, this might help you: http://blog.blackballsoftware.com/2010/11/03/making-a-facebook-wall-post-using-the-new-graph-api-and-c/

Comment: Hi Neil, it's customary in StackOverflow answers to include a summary of the contents of a link or the highlights that specifically answer the question. The goal of SE sites is to become a resource of knowledge, of answers, for years to come. With a link-only answer (comment), the op must dig through another resource to locate an answer he/she might not be sure about. Most importantly, if your link were to ever break, your answer is useless for anyone who visits this page in the future. Consider making an [edit] to your answer to add more details. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I'll incorporate your advise in my future postings and make sure my answer is more than a link.